# How much energy do all the world's emails use?

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-hardware, statistics

I have heard high level statistics and headlines around

> blockchain uses more energy than the Netherlands

I am interested to compare this quantitatively to other utilities, for example email and social media.

How much energy does all the world's emails use?

Another way to think of this: how much energy would be saved if everyone immediately stopped sending emails, and they didn't use any substitute for emails?

Comment: IT is doing its bit for sustainability: they are reusing packets. (Joke).

Comment: So the bit-bucket goes to  recycling now. Do I have to segregate ones and zeros?

Comment: I'm sure all the HD video flying around has nothing to do with it either...

Comment: @PeteW energy from HD Video consumption would probably be a more interesting question! Next time..